# Неправильный вывод при использовании регулярных выражений

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

```
Pattern pt = Pattern.compile("([0-1\\s]){1,}([+-/*//^]){1}([\\s0-1]{1,})");
if (scan.findInLine(pt) != null) {
    if (scan.match().group(1) != null) {
        System.out.println("g1= "+(scan.match().group(1)));
        System.out.println("g2= "+(scan.match().group(2)));
        System.out.println("g3= "+(scan.match().group(3)));
    }
}
```

input

```
11001-100011
```

output

```
g1= 1
g2= -
g3= 100011
```

g1 = должна быть 11001 но нет что не правильно?

Answer (score 0):

не проще ли

```
([0-9]+)(\-)([0-9]+)
```

https://regex101.com/r/CpYHny/1

?

Хотя может я не знаю целиком что вы делаете)

---

В целом вы применяете квантификатор к выбранной группе, а не к набору символов (которые находятся в квадратных скобках). Соответственно квантификатор надо ставить именно после **квадратных** скобок, а не после круглых

Answer (score 0):

> g1 = должна быть 11001 но нет что не правильно?

Не должна и даже не может. Вот как выглядит g1: `([0-1\\s])` - очевидно, что это один символ, а не пять.

> 11001

Надо в регулярке переставить скобку и вместо `([0-1\\s]){1,}` написать `([0-1\\s]{1,})`, а потом ещё подумать и заменить `{1,}` на `+`: `([0-1\\s]+)`.